# access all packets from Pcap file

Tags: python, django, pcap

I am trying to access some information from pcap file. 
I am able to do for a single packet, and pcap file have multiple packet.

I coded this into **Django**.

What should I add into this code by which it return all packet information

```
testcap = open("Test_1.pcap")
capfile = savefile.load_savefile(testcap, verbose=True)

for i in range(len(capfile.packets)):

    ip_packet = ip.IP(binascii.unhexlify(ethernet.Ethernet(capfile.packets[i].raw()).payload));
    mac_packet = ethernet.Ethernet(capfile.packets[i].raw());
    packet = capfile.packets[i];



def index(request):
    answer = [

             str(packet.timestamp),
             str(packet.packet_len),
             str(mac_packet.src),
             str(mac_packet.dst),
             str(ip_packet.src),
             str(ip_packet.dst),
              ]

    return HttpResponse("<br>" . join(answer))
```

I tried for looping also still its not working.

Comment: Where are you _looping_ in this code? I see you are just using first packet to return response. `packet = capfile.packets[0];`

Comment: yes, I remove that looping bcs that was not working, can you suggest me proper looping

Comment: How did you loop? It looks just iterating capfile.packets would work.

Comment: @kaitoy I added loop, how I was trying, it returning last packet information only.